# Как сделать функцию, обрабатывающую неизвестное кол-во переменных?

Tags: c++, функции

Функция вроде и обрабатывает значения, но добавляет ещё откуда то из вне, не знаю как переписать нормально или по другому.

```cpp
void MyFunc(int a,...){
    int *P=&a; 

    while (*P){
        cout << *P <<" ";
        P+=sizeof(int)/2;
    }


}
int main(){
    MyFunc(4,3,2,1,5,6,7,8,5);


}
```

Comment: Описания разве нигде нет? https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/functions-with-variable-argument-lists-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: Это делается по другому. Читайте [man stdarg](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/va_start.3.html)

Comment: *Неизвестное* количество переменных обработать никак не получится, нужно каким-то способом передать в функцию количество переменных. Можно передать количество первым параметром, а можно использовать строку формата, как это сделано в функции `printf`.

Comment: @maestro ...или использовать шаблоны, раз уж это C++.

Comment: Если они все одинаковые, то можно принимать на вход `std::array`, `std::span` ну или, на худой конец, `::std::initializer_list`.

Answer (score 2):

Старыми сишными `...` аргументами в C++ лучше не пользоваться, потому что они никак не дают защититься от передачи аргументов неправильных типов (или неправильного количества).

Лучше всего использовать `std::span`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void foo(std::span<const int> s)
{
    for (int x : s)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo({{1,2,3,4}}); // В С++26 можно с одинарными `{...}`.

    // Или так:
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    foo(arr);
}
```

Есть еще варианты с `std::vector`, `std::initializer_list`, или со ссылкой на массив, но это все хуже, потому что заставляет пользователя создавать определенный контейнер.

А `span` принимает любой контейнер, в котором элементы расположены в памяти подряд.

---

Есть еще вариант с шаблоном с переменным количеством аргументов. Казалось бы, красивый синтаксис без фигурных скобок, но он добавляет проблем: функцию нельзя спрятать в .cpp-шник; вам могут передать аргументы разных типов и надо как-то нормально с этим справиться (вызвать ошибку компиляции или сконвертировать в нужный тип); количество элементов фиксируется во время компиляции (если вам это низачем не нужно, то лучше не ограничивать пользователя).

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...P>
void foo(const P &... s)
{
    ((std::cout << s << '\n'), ...);
}

int main()
{
    foo(1,2,3,4);
}
```

---

Если хочется сделать совсем красиво и нет отвращения к шаблонам, тогда используйте C++20 ranges. Работает как первый вариант, но принимает совершенно любой контейнер.

```
#include <concepts>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

template <std::ranges::input_range R = std::initializer_list<int>>
requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, int>
void foo(R&& range)
{
    for (int x : range)
        std::cout << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    foo({1,2,3,4});

    // Или так:
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    foo(arr);
}
```